# Using Firesharp in Xamarin.Forms to get Data from Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, fire-sharp

I want to push and get Recipe-Data from my Firebase Database in Xamarin.Forms with the Firesharp Plugin.

My Model Class is the Recipe Class:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public string title { get; set; }

    public string workTime { get; set; }

    public string degreeOfDifficulty { get; set; }

    public string caloriesPerPerson { get; set; }

    public string preparation { get; set; }

    public string cookingBakingTime { get; set; }

    public string restTime { get; set; }

    public int portions { get; set; }

    public string pictureSource { get; set; }

    public List<Ingredient> ingredients { get; set; }


    public Recipe()
    {
        ingredients = new List<Ingredient>();
    }
}
```

So Push Recipe-Objects to the Firebase DB works:

```
 public async Task PushRecipe(Recipe recipe)
    {
        IFirebaseClient client = new FirebaseClient(config);

        client.Push("Recipes", recipe);

    }
```

[Firebase Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLP6y.png)

But when i want to get Data from the Database i get an Error..

```
public async Task<List<Recipe>> GetAllRecipes()
    {
        IFirebaseClient client = new FirebaseClient(config);

        FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetAsync("Recipes");

        try
        {

            List<Recipe> recipelist = response.ResultAs<List<Recipe>>();

            return recipelist;

        } catch (Exception e){

        }

        return null;

    }
```

After this:

```
List<Recipe> recipelist = response.ResultAs<List<Recipe>>();
```

this Exception comes..

"{Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[dignaBon_App.Models.Recipe]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correc…}"

I don´t understand why i can´t get Data from the Database back..

Can someone help me?

Comment: your query returns a single object, but you are trying to deserialize into an array.  Try deserializing into a Recipe instead of a List< Recipe>

Comment: The response contains a json of all Recipe Objects, but he cant deserialize it.. i must have a List<Recipe> because i want all Recipes which are in the Database.. any suggestions?

Comment: what does the actual json returned by Firebase look like?

Answer (score 0):

You need instatiate the "config" with your firebase secret address key. Go to your Firebase console for this.